# How to draw a diagram in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to replicate this figure, that I did in word, in LaTeX, I don't what to insert just the figure (the easiest way to incorporate the image) but to create it from zero. Any suggestion or idea?

[image]

Comment: You seem to have worked out that [`TikZ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) can be used for such a diagram given the tags, why not take a look at [Min­i­mal in­tro­duc­tion to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) and take a look at other questions on this site which use [tag:tikz-pgf] and have a first go at drawing this diagram yourself.

Comment: @DaiBowen Yes, I have used `TikZ` before, but I haven't figured out yet how to incorporate the two rectangles of "Space of the Theory" and "Space of measurement and observation". I image that plotting it like a function would help, but that's my problem. I don't know how to incorporate the words into the whole graphics. I will check again the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to plot the rectangles. Just define coordinates and draw the rectangles you want using them.

Comment: If the code in your question is a solution, please post it as an answer instead of including it in the question. It is perfectly fine to answer ones own question, and it helps distinguish the question from the answer.

Comment: `\scriptsize` is a switch not a command, so you would use it like `{\scriptsize foo bar baz}` not `\scriptsize{foo bar baz}`. But here you would not need any braces

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you, I just edited and posted the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a version that doesn't rely on absolute coordinates to the extent that your code does. Updated code a bit, moved some text below the line, added the arrows you have in your example, and used the `fit` library to draw the surrounding frame (that could in hindsight be done with `\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);` instead.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,arrows.meta,positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  axis/.style={very thick,<->,>=Latex},
  MyArrow/.style={-Stealth},
  every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
  node distance=3mm]

\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\draw[axis] (-2.5, 0) -- (12.5,0)
  coordinate (right) coordinate [pos=0] (left)
  node[pos=0.95,below] {Higher}
  node[pos=0.93,above,align=center,font=\bfseries\scriptsize] {Phenomenom\\Amplitude};
\draw[axis] (0, -3) -- (0,3.5) 
  node[pos=0.03,left] (lower) {Lower}
  node[pos=0.97,left] {Higher}
  node[above] (abslev) {\textbf{Abstraction level}};
\node [above left,
       minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=3cm,
       draw,align=center,font=\bfseries\scriptsize] (theory) at (origin) {Space of\\Theory};
\node [below left,
       minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=2.4cm,
       draw,align=center,font=\bfseries\scriptsize] (obs) at (origin) {Space of\\Measurement\\and\\Observation};

\node [below right] at (origin) {Lower};

\node [above=2mm,align=center] (empreg) at (6,0) {%
\textbf{Empirical regularities -- Observable concepts:}%
  };

\node [above=of empreg,align=center] (subthe) {%
\textbf{Substantive Theories:}\\%
\textit{Dualist; Structuralist; Regulationist; Voluntarist}%
  };

\node [above=of subthe,xshift=1cm,align=center] (genthe) {%
\textbf{General Theory:}\\%
\textit{Institutionalism Political Economy}%
  };
\node [above=of genthe,xshift=1cm,align=center] (para) {%
\textbf{Paradigm:}\\%
\textit{Structural Constructivism}%
  };

\draw[MyArrow] (para) -- (genthe);
\draw[MyArrow] (genthe) -- (subthe);
\draw[MyArrow] (subthe) -- (empreg);

\node [below=4mm of empreg,align=center,font=\itshape\scriptsize] (ecstr) {%
Political Structure: State, Government, Regulatory Framework, Social Class\\
Economic Structure: Market, Work-Employment, Capital\\
Public Policies: Development, Social, Labour, Vocational Training\\
Workers: Informal and Formal Sector – Self-Employment, Conditions};

% three arrows
\draw [-Stealth] (empreg.south) -- (ecstr.north);
\draw [-Stealth] ([xshift=3mm]empreg.south) -- ([xshift=3mm]ecstr.north);
\draw [-Stealth] ([xshift=-3mm]empreg.south) -- ([xshift=-3mm]ecstr.north);

% draw rectangle
\node [fit=(left)(right)(lower)(abslev),draw,inner xsep=0pt] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried it with this code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Levels of abstraction in the theoretical framework} \label{fig:1}
\vspace*{-5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, transform shape]
%\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (15,7); %Lineas guias 
\draw[thick] (0,1) rectangle (15,7); %Rectangulo de afuera
\draw[thick, <->] (0, 3) -- (15,3); %Linea eje imaginario X
\draw[thick, <->] (2.5, 1) -- (2.5,6.5); %Linea eje imaginario de Y 
\draw[thick] (0,1.5) rectangle (2.5,3); % Space of Measurement Rectangulo
\draw[thick] (0,3) rectangle (2.5, 6.125); %Space of Theory Rectangulo
\draw[->] (11.5,6) -- (11,5.75) ; %Conector entre Paradigma y Teoría General
\draw[->] (10.5,5) -- (10,4.75) ; %Teoría General y Teoría Sustantiva
\draw[->] (9.5,4) -- (9,3.75) ; %Teoría Sustantiva y Regularidades empíricas
\draw[->] (8.5, 3.25) -- (8.5, 2.75) ; % Linea que conecta a Regularidades empiricas
\draw[->] (8, 3.25) -- (8, 2.75) ; % Linea que conecta a Regularidades empiricas
\draw[->] (9, 3.25) -- (9, 2.75) ; % Linea que conecta a Regularidades empiricas
\node at (14,3.5) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Phenomenom}}};
\node at (14,3.2) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Amplitute}}};
\node at (14,2.8) {\scriptsize{Higher}};
\node at (3,2.8) {\scriptsize{Lower}};
\node at (2.5,6.7) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Abstraction Level}}};
\node at (2,6.3) {\scriptsize{Higher}};
\node at (2,1.25) {\scriptsize{Lower}}; 
\node at (1.25, 2.55) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Space of}}};
\node at (1.25, 2.25) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Measurment and}}};
\node at (1.25, 1.95) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Observation}}};
\node at (1.25, 4.7) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Space of}}};
\node at (1.25, 4.4) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Theory}}};
\node at (11.5, 6.55) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Paradigm:}}};
\node at (11.5, 6.25) {\scriptsize{\textit{Structural Constructivism}}};
\node at (10.5, 5.55) {\scriptsize{\textbf{General Theory:}}};
\node at (10.5, 5.25) {\scriptsize{\textit{Institutionalism Political Economy}}};
\node at (9.5, 4.55) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Substantive Theories:}}};
\node at (9.5, 4.25) {\scriptsize{\textit{Dualist; Structuralist; Regulationist; Voluntarist}}};
\node at (8.5, 3.5) {\scriptsize{\textbf{Empirical regularities - Observable concepts:}}};
\node at (8.5, 2.45) {\scriptsize{\textit{Political Structure: State, Government, Regulatory Framework, Social Class}}};
\node at (8.5, 2.15) {\scriptsize{\textit{Economic Structure: Market, Work-Employment, Capital}}};
\node at (8.5, 1.85) {\scriptsize{\textit{Public Policies: Development, Social, Labour, Vocational Training}}};
\node at (8.5, 1.55) {\scriptsize{\textit{Workers: Informal and Formal Sector – Self-Employment, Conditions}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{-2.5mm}
\caption*{{\scriptsize\textit{\textbf{Source:} Own theoretical diagram based on  Sautu, Boniolo, Dalle \& Elbert (2005)}}}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

And it worked properly.

My result is:

[image]

This is different from the first diagram because I realized that the empirical regularities should be below the line.

Comment: I doubt that this work properly. You have float environment captured into non float:  newer use `\begin{center}\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}\end{center}`. Correct is `\begin{figure}\centering ... \end{figure}`. Also is wrong `scriptsize{<your text>}`. `\scriptisize` is command and not an environment! Besides this your code is unnecessary complicated. I strongly encourage you to read TikZ manual, at list part III: Tikz ist kein Zeichenprogramm and study  nice Torbjørn T. answer!

Comment: @Zarko Actually, it worked well for me. And yes, I'm new with TiKZ, even though I have used LaTeX before, in terms of figures and diagrams, I am always struggling with it. This diagram was my first one with the package. I will study the manual. Thank you.